# Adding Canvas within Canvas but as a separate Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, canvas, bitmap

I'm creating a game where I use a custom view.I use `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` to draw my game with touch listeners.Now that I'm in need of a bitmap to be drawn on the same canvas but running on a different thread,I don't know how to proceed.The thread I create must draw the bitmap for a specific time only.I tried creating another custom view implementing runnable and drawing the bitmap i need.But i dont know where to call it.As I'm new to programming,guide me on how to deal with this idea of mine.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What You are trying might get You in problems.
AFAIK UI-manipulation may only be done in UI thread.Means,any other thread,which is not same thread id than the ui thread,will cause an cross thread exception.How ever, You can invoke asynchroneous method invocation in the ui thread. This should give a bit more information. http://download.eclipse.org/technology/swtbot/galileo/dev-build/apidocs/org/eclipse/swtbot/swt/finder/finders/UIThreadRunnable.html As You are new to programming You should not statr with such heavy things as threading unless You studied them in depth, and much You must study.

Comment: Yes as you said i came through errors with thread.Im very much interested with multi threading concepts.Can you suggest me some book or any kind of online resource that will help me gain more knowledge regarding this concept?

Comment: I added it as an answer because of better formatting.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I recommend You to follow this order ( and how often to read ? That often, until You understand everything in each topic ).

There we go:

**Basics to go :**

1. [Process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29)
2. [Thread](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computing%29)
3. [Multithreading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multithreading_%28computer_architecture%29)
4. [Multithreading 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multithreading_%28software%29#Multithreading)
5. [All about multithreading 1](http://ashishkhandelwal.arkutil.com/csharp/all-about-multithread-programming-concept-issues-and-synchronization/)
6. [Original docs about mt ( java )](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-5257/6je9h032e/index.html)
7. [mt programming java](http://www.buyya.com/java/Chapter14.pdf)
8. [Basics of android mt programming](http://developer.samsung.com/android/technical-docs/Basics-of-multi-threading-in-Android)

I suppose, You now will have much to read. 
But keep in mind, You must do it. Threading can bring You in situations, where You almost cen get lost, if one thread hangs up and or blocks some other thread. Therefore You need all the background information, because, once, You are in trouble, You then know, where to look first.

Have fun.

Comment: Its quite a lot to learn.Thanks a lot !!! :)

Comment: For one go:create class which inherits from Thread.Create an interface,which is implemented by this class (basic event handling stuff).Either let the activity also implement this interface and call its method from the interface method in the inherited thread class,or give the activity a public method which you call.When?When You started the thread and Your time consuming job is done.Inside the public method of activity(or inside the if-method of activity) You then will still be in the other thread but inside the activity. And afaik this has a method,runOnUIThread,voila,back in ui thread.

Comment: Why downvoted? If this is not an acceptable and helpful answer, I would like to know, what else is one.